# Rmwc Dialog Component Fails to build?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to use the RMWC dialog component - https://rmwc.io/dialogs in my App.

but as soon as i import the library

```
import {Dialog} from "@rmwc/dialog";
```

Typescript compiler starts complaining

```
[at-loader] ./node_modules/@rmwc/textfield/dist/index.d.ts:83:1302 
    TS2344: Type 'K' does not satisfy the constraint '"input" | "progress" | "select" | "error" | "scroll" | "reset" | "drag" | "submit" | "abort" | "animationcancel" | "animationend" | "animationiteration" | "animationstart" | ... 70 more ... | "wheel"'.
  Type '"input" | "progress" | "select" | "error" | "scroll" | "reset" | "drag" | "submit" | "abort" | "animationcancel" | "animationend" | "animationiteration" | "animationstart" | ... 72 more ... | "selectstart"' is not assignable to type '"input" | "progress" | "select" | "error" | "scroll" | "reset" | "drag" | "submit" | "abort" | "animationcancel" | "animationend" | "animationiteration" | "animationstart" | ... 70 more ... | "wheel"'.
    Type '"selectionchange"' is not assignable to type '"input" | "progress" | "select" | "error" | "scroll" | "reset" | "drag" | "submit" | "abort" | "animationcancel" | "animationend" | "animationiteration" | "animationstart" | ... 70 more ... | "wheel"'.
      Type 'K' is not assignable to type '"wheel"'.
        Type '"input" | "progress" | "select" | "error" | "scroll" | "reset" | "drag" | "submit" | "abort" | "animationcancel" | "animationend" | "animationiteration" | "animationstart" | ... 72 more ... | "selectstart"' is not assignable to type '"wheel"'.
          Type '"input"' is not assignable to type '"wheel"'.
```

What might be the Cause of this problem . ? I am confused to where to start looking for the options.

My tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "include": [
    "./app/**/*"
  ]
}
```

**Update Some confusion with the answer after using 3.6.2 version**

**Fixed Version for the usage**

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rmwc/types": "5.6.0",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "@types/react": "16.8.23",
    "react-dom": "16.8.6",
    "typescript": "3.6.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "rmwc": "5.6.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: why can't you reproduce this in codesandbox?

Comment: @Peter I am trying desperately to do so but for some odd reason i am not able to really strange, i have opened a issue in rmwc too but still confused

Comment: perhaps you should link the issue you opened and provide the codesandbox anyways.

Comment: okay i will just add the issue link and try and just add the component give me some time

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using?

Comment: `"typescript": "3.5.3"`

Comment: @Peter the stranger thing is the error comes up in the textfield component when i import the dialog component and i cannot understand the connection between the two

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updating your TypeScript version to at least `3.6.2` should fix this issue. In the error message you can see it's missing `selectionchange`. This event type has been added to the TypeScript DOM lib in version `3.6.2`.

#### Detailed explanation

We start out in the type definitions file [`@rmwc/dialog/dist/index.d.ts`](https://unpkg.com/browse/@rmwc/dialog@5.6.0/dist/index.d.ts):

```js
export * from './dialog';
export * from './dialog-queue';
```

Moving on to [`dialog-queue.d.ts`](https://unpkg.com/browse/@rmwc/dialog@5.6.0/dist/dialog-queue.d.ts) we can see that it imports `@rmwc/textfield`. That's why those types even get processed even though you import the dialog package.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { SimpleDialogProps, DialogOnCloseEventT } from './dialog';
import { ArrayEmitter } from '@rmwc/base';
import { TextFieldProps } from '@rmwc/textfield';
```

Looking at [`@rmwc/textfield/dist/index.d.ts`](https://unpkg.com/browse/@rmwc/textfield@5.6.0/dist/index.d.ts) line 83 we see this:
(parts omitted and re-formatted for readability)

```js
registerInputInteractionHandler:
    <K extends "error" | "input" | /*...*/ "selectionchange" /*...*/ | "wheel">
    (evtType: K, handler: SpecificEventListener<K>) => void;
```

The generic parameter `K` extends a huge union type of allowed event names. This list of names also includes `"selectionchange"`. `K` is then passed to `SpecificEventListener` which is imported from `@material/base`.

Continuing in [`@material/base/types.d.ts`](https://unpkg.com/browse/@material/base@3.1.0/types.d.ts) we see this:

```js
export declare type EventType = keyof GlobalEventHandlersEventMap;
export declare type SpecificEventListener<K extends EventType> = (evt: GlobalEventHandlersEventMap[K]) => void;
```

The parameter `K` from before must extend `EventType`. `keyof GlobalEventHandlersEventMap` constructs a union type of all property names of the `GlobalEventHandlersEventMap`.

Where does `GlobalEventHandlersEventMap` come from? It's defined in `lib.dom.d.ts` that ships with TypeScript itself. Looking at the version history of the file, we can see that `selectionchange` was added in [this commit](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/commit/00bf32ca3967b07e8663d0cd2b3e2bbf572da88b#diff-46fd87925e4552c166ec188712741c3fR5462) for version `3.6.2`.

Comment: Thanks for such a great explanation i wish i could shake hands with you , wish to look at the problem with your lens and deep dive to the issue . thanks again

Comment: Just a quick update today i was able to update the library but it still fails and checked the commit it is tagged to `3.6.3` can you please check once [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/commit/00bf32ca3967b07e8663d0cd2b3e2bbf572da88b#diff-46fd87925e4552c166ec188712741c3fR5462) . it is tagged to 3.6.3 any reason when it changed

Comment: Actually that just seems to be Github showing you the latest tag that includes this commit. If you click the 3 dots next to it, you'll see a whole list of tags.
However this also means I was wrong about this change having been introduced in 3.6.2. It's actually been there since 3.3.4000. So that explains why updating didn't help. I'll try to reproduce this locally and get back to you.

Comment: Hey thanks I have again started rubbing my head against those changes ..

Comment: So when I try to reproduce your issue, it works fine for me. What I did is install the latest versions of `typescript`, `react`, `@types/react` and `@rmwc/dialog`.
I suspect the problem is some kind of incompatibility between package versions. Please let me know the exact package versions you're using. Either by sharing your whole lock file or manually specifying the versions of at least all packages mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I have posted all my versions as part of an update to the question..Thanks for helping out

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I still can't reproduce the issue. It could be because of other (not explicitly installed) dependencies or because of some other reason. But without being able to reproduce it it's hard for me to help.
The best thing would be if you could set up a minimal example of the problem in a public repo.

Comment: i will try that up